# MySQL: get record within polygon

Tags: mysql, sql, google-maps, polygon, spatial

I have a table in database with following with latitude and longitude attribute

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(12,8) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(12,8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `companies` (`ID`, `title`, `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES 
(NULL, 'John and SOns', '25.29064622', '55.368462502'), 
(NULL, 'Evas', '25.28862850', '55.40107816');
```

On google map I have a polyline feature, where user can draw a polyline, so we can show all companies which are within that polygon.

Here is map image

[image]

Google may giving an array of latitude longitude
[image]

How I can query to fetch all records from database which lies within draw polygon?

Comment: Provided you're happy to work with (a projection into) Euclidean geometry, then from MySQL v5.7.5 [`ST_Contains()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains) will do exactly what you want; earlier versions of MySQL can only test against the *minimum bounding rectangle* of the specified polygon, using [`MBRContains()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-relation-functions-mysql-specific.html#function_mbrcontains).

Comment: I am using MySQL v5.6.28,  As google map  bounds.getCenter() function give polygon center latitude and longitude, so is there any way we can get polygon radius  so can query by distance  in database.

Comment: If you're happy with that sort of approximation, what's wrong with `MBRContains()`?

Comment: For MBRContains() compare should I store lat long in same column?

Comment: It'd be best to store both Lat and Long in a single `POINT` type column, since then you can build spatial R-Tree indexes upon it (which greatly assist in performing bounded search across 2 dimensions, as you want here).

Answer (score 0):

You should find that if you write your query as:

```
select ID,title from companies where st_within(point(companies.longitude,companies.latitude),  ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((75.80278873443604 26.863847231536703, 75.79540729522705 26.85136594544373, 75.81798076629639 26.851595674802315,75.80278873443604 26.863847231536703))'));
```

then is should work.